# Why is $\cos(\infty)$ undefined?

Tags: trigonometry, infinity

Why is $\cos(\infty)$ undefined?

I really don't understand this. Is it because we can't pinpoint an exact value for cos at infinity?

Comment: $\cos$ is only defined for the reals. As $x \to \infty$, $\cos x$ takes values $\pm 1$ infinitely often, so it cannot have a limit.

Comment: First of all, what is $\infty$? It is not a real number, that much can be said. The point is,  the first way of defining the function value at infinity that comes to mind, is that *if* $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$ (which has a definition that does not invoke the symbol $\infty$ itself) exists, then we can call this quantity as $\cos(\infty)$. Unfortunately, it does not exist, so that is why $\cos(\infty)$ may not be definable in this way. Note that if you did not mind $\cos$ being discontinuous (on one-point-compactification), then $\cos(\infty)$ can be given an arbitrary value. No use, though

Comment: You could extend the definition of $\cos$ to be defined for the symbol $\infty$, but what good would that do?

Comment: I answered it but there is a very good chance that your question will be deleted. It would have been better If you had described how you came upon $\cos \infty$ is undefined and tried to explain more clearly why that is confusing.  MSE requires that questions should include some sort of context and some indication of what level of mathematics you are at.

Comment: @stevengregory okay, i'll keep that in mind next time. Thank you for your answer! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost understand it.

We don't need to pinpoint an exact value, but we do need to pinpoint a value, say $L$, that, as $x$ gets larger, then the value of $\cos x$ gets closer to $L$. Since $\cos x$ is always wiggling between $-1$ and $1$, we can't do that.

Comment: +1 very clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

because you cannot attribute it a value. The value of $cos(\infty)$ would be defined as:
$$
cos(\infty)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}cos(x)
$$ 
If this limit was well defined then for **any** sequence $a_n\rightarrow \infty$ one would have:
$$
cos(\infty)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}cos(a_n)
$$
giving the **same** value.

However if you consider $a_n=2n\pi$ and $b_n=(2n+1)\pi$ you get:
\begin{align*}
cos(\infty)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}cos(a_n)=+1 \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}cos(b_n)=-1
\end{align*}
As these values are differents, the limit does not exist, thus $cos(\infty)$ is not defined.